# Suppress unnecessary output to config.h.in

Tags: autotools, autoconf, m4

When AC_CHECK_HEADERS is invoked inside m4_foreach_w, autoheader(2.65) seems to generate a bogus template.  For example:

```
m4_foreach_w([hdr],[[foo.h] [bar.h]],
    [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_]m4_translit(m4_toupper(hdr),[/.],[__]),[1],
        [Define to 1 if ]hdr[ is available])]
    [AC_CHECK_HEADERS([hdr])]
)
```

Causes `config.h.in` (assuming `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])`) to have a template:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the <hdr> header file.*/
#undef HAVE_HDR
```

Is there any way to avoid that bogus template?  Note that the `m4_foreach_w` is being invoked inside a macro and the actual text is `m4_foreach_w([hdr],[$1],` and I'm wondering if I have an m4 quoting issue, but I suspect the problem is more fundamental.  Which is to say, I always assume I've misquoted the m4--but that does not seem to be the problem here.  Rather, `autoheader` is scanning the text without honoring the `m4_foreach_w`.  I don't think the template causes any problems, but it looks really weird in the final `config.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `autoheader` does not "scan" `configure.ac`.  Rather, it runs `configure.ac` through `m4` in trace mode, in order to catch low-level calls to `AC_DEFINE_TRACE_LITERAL` (which is called indirectly by `AC_DEFINE`) and to `AH_OUTPUT` (called by`AC_CHECK_HEADERS`).  So because everything goes through `m4`, `autoheader` does not ignore `m4_foreach`.  However it sees the arguments the way they are actually received by the macros.

You can see the problem in your code by tracing the calls to `AC_DEFINE` and `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` in your `configure.ac`:

```
% cat configure.ac
AC_INIT(somelib.so, 1.0, someone@somewhere.com)
m4_foreach_w([hdr],[[foo.h] [bar.h]], [
     AC_DEFINE([HAVE_]m4_translit(m4_toupper(hdr),[/.],[__]),[1],
        [Define to 1 if ]hdr[ is available])
     AC_CHECK_HEADERS([hdr])
])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_OUTPUT
% autoconf -t AC_DEFINE -t AC_CHECK_HEADERS
configure.ac:3:AC_DEFINE:HAVE_FOO_H:1:Define to 1 if foo.h is available
configure.ac:3:AC_CHECK_HEADERS:hdr
configure.ac:3:AC_DEFINE:STDC_HEADERS:1:Define to 1 if you have the ANSI C header files.
configure.ac:3:AC_CHECK_HEADERS:sys/types.h sys/stat.h stdlib.h string.h memory.h strings.h inttypes.h stdint.h unistd.h:::$ac_includes_default
configure.ac:3:AC_DEFINE:HAVE_BAR_H:1:Define to 1 if bar.h is available
configure.ac:3:AC_CHECK_HEADERS:hdr
```

So we see that `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` is called twice with `hdr` as argument.  While in the call to AC_DEFINE, `hdr` has been correctly expanded.  That's because `hdr` is quoted one more time in your call to `AC_CHECK_HEADERS`, preventing its expansion.

I'd fix it this way:

```
m4_foreach_w([hdr],[[foo.h] [bar.h]], [
     AC_DEFINE([HAVE_]m4_translit(m4_toupper(hdr),[/.],[__]),[1],
        [Define to 1 if ]hdr[ is available])
     AC_CHECK_HEADERS(hdr)
])
```

(But that is still assuming that the names foo.h and bar.h will never trigger any macro.)